# Why is this transition acting differently on Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: html, css, svg, cross-browser

I have the following SVG animation (it's a pretty big snippet, see 'Show code snippet'):

```css
.logo > .logo-compass-frame {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 15;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.logo > .logo-compass-north, .logo > .logo-compass-south {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 8;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.logo > .logo-compass-south {
  fill: none;
}

.logo > .logo-compass-center {
  fill: black;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.logo > .logo-compass-north, .logo > .logo-compass-south, .logo > .logo-compass-center {
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

.logo:hover > .logo-compass-north, .logo:hover > .logo-compass-south {
  transform-origin: center;
}

.logo:hover > .logo-compass-north {

  transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1.5) translate(10px);
}

.logo:hover > .logo-compass-south {
  transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1.5) translate(-10px);
}

.logo:hover > .logo-compass-center {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg class="logo" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 272.6 272.6">
  <circle class="logo-compass-frame" cx="136.3" cy="136.3" r="105.8" />
  <polygon class="logo-compass-north" points="138,63.6 123.8,110.5 138,134.5 152.2,110.5" />
  <polygon class="logo-compass-south" points="138,209 152.2,162.1 138,138.1 123.8,162.1" />
  <circle class="logo-compass-center" cx="138" cy="136.6" r="5.7" />
</svg>
```

The problem is that it acts differently on just Firefox (haven't tested on Edge or IE as I'm on macOS). For WebKit browsers and Opera, I get:

Chrome 60.0.3112.90:

[image]

Safari 10.1:

[image]

Opera 47.0.2631.39:

[image]

Firefox 54.0.1:

[image]

Something fishy is going on. I haven't tried Edge or IE, so maybe it's some kind of CSS specification-compliance issue? I thought maybe `transform-origin` was not being supported as it's an experimental technology, but adding `-moz-transform-origin` did nothing, and MDN reports that `transform-origin` is supported now.

Why are the transitions acting differently on different browsers, and is it possible to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really use percentage values for transform-origin right now because percentage values are treated differently in Chrome and Firefox. That applies also to pseudo values like "center" which is defined to be equivalent to "50%".

You need to use absolute pixel values instead to be cross-browser compatible.

```css
.logo > .logo-compass-frame {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 15;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.logo > .logo-compass-north, .logo > .logo-compass-south {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 8;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.logo > .logo-compass-south {
  fill: none;
}

.logo > .logo-compass-center {
  fill: black;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.logo > .logo-compass-north, .logo > .logo-compass-south, .logo > .logo-compass-center {
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

.logo:hover > .logo-compass-north {
  transform-origin: 138px 99px;
}

.logo:hover > .logo-compass-south {
  transform-origin: 138px 173.5px;
}

.logo:hover > .logo-compass-north {

  transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1.5) translate(10px);
}

.logo:hover > .logo-compass-south {
  transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1.5) translate(-10px);
}

.logo:hover > .logo-compass-center {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg class="logo" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 272.6 272.6">
  <circle class="logo-compass-frame" cx="136.3" cy="136.3" r="105.8" />
  <polygon class="logo-compass-north" points="138,63.6 123.8,110.5 138,134.5 152.2,110.5" />
  <polygon class="logo-compass-south" points="138,209 152.2,162.1 138,138.1 123.8,162.1" />
  <circle class="logo-compass-center" cx="138" cy="136.6" r="5.7" />
</svg>
```

**Update**

I've worked out why Firefox was behaving differently.  It is not a bug.  Firefox is actually correct.  It is because Firefox is correctly interpreting the spec and the other browsers are not.

The direct cause is due to the fact that we were specifying the `transform-origin` in the `:hover` rule.  So the origin was being interpolated (ie. moving) as well.  The fix is to either:

1. Specify that we only want to transition the transform property.

   ```
   transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
   ```
2. Or move the `transform-origin` out of the hover rule.

Below is an updated version that uses approach #2.

```css
.logo > .logo-compass-frame {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 15;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.logo > .logo-compass-north {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 8;
  transform-origin: 138px 99px;
}

.logo > .logo-compass-south {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 8;
  fill: none;
  transform-origin: 138px 173.5px;
}

.logo > .logo-compass-center {
  fill: black;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.logo > .logo-compass-north, .logo > .logo-compass-south, .logo > .logo-compass-center {
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

.logo:hover > .logo-compass-north {
  transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1.5) translate(10px);
}

.logo:hover > .logo-compass-south {
  transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1.5) translate(-10px);
}

.logo:hover > .logo-compass-center {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg class="logo" width="300px" viewBox="0 0 272.6 272.6">
  <circle class="logo-compass-frame" cx="136.3" cy="136.3" r="105.8" />
  <polygon class="logo-compass-north" points="138,63.6 123.8,110.5 138,134.5 152.2,110.5" />
  <polygon class="logo-compass-south" points="138,209 152.2,162.1 138,138.1 123.8,162.1" />
  <circle class="logo-compass-center" cx="138" cy="136.6" r="5.7" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Ahh yes. I suspected `transform-origin` but I forgot that `center` was just an alias for percentage values, and FF doesn't fully support that yet. Thanks!

Comment: Also -- how exactly did you calculate the pixel values? In actuality, my logo is on a navbar.

Comment: I find the centre by opening the dev tools and selecting the element of interest with the element selector tool. Then in the console I type: `var b=$0.getBBox();`. Then `b.x+b.width/2` and `b.y+b.height/2`.

Comment: @AndrewLi FF **does** fully support that. It's Chrome that's wrong. Chrome/Opera behaviour is scheduled to align with Firefox and the w3c specification not the other way round.

Comment: Is there any plausible way to "keep" my current animation or rewrite it so it's spec-compliant but looks the same?

Comment: @AndrewLi I can't really explain the remaining strange behaviour in Firefox. It appears to be an error in the way the transform is being interpolated in the animation.  I am going to investigate.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Thanks a lot!